# I have number of formats like ####-##-##, (###)-###-####, I want to change value of textfield to given format, How to achieve it.?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have number of formats like ####-##-##, (###)-###-####, I want to change value of textfield to given format, How to achieve it.?

one way is manually check string and change it to string, that i know, is there some other efficient way to do this? Please let me, I am getting different formats for textfields like:

```
**Format1** for Textfield1 : ####-###-### [I want to convert enter text of field to this format like 3333-333-333]
**Format2** for Textfield2 : (###)-###-#### [I want to convert enter text of field to this format like (333)-333-3333]
**Format3** for Textfield3 : ##-##-## [I want to convert enter text of field to this format like 33-33-33]
```

etc. Please let me know, if there is some efficient way to handle it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Format 2**

Add if condition in textfield delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:`

```
 if (textField == self.addressPhoneNumberTextField) {
    int length = (int)[self getLength:textField.text];
    //NSLog(@"Length  =  %d ",length);

    NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789\b"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[characterSet invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
        return NO;
    }

    if(length == 10)
    {
        if(range.length == 0)
            return NO;
    }

    if(length == 3)
    {
        NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) ",num];

        if(range.length > 0)
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:3]];
    }
    else if(length == 6)
    {
        NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
        //NSLog(@"%@",[num  substringToIndex:3]);
        //NSLog(@"%@",[num substringFromIndex:3]);
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-",[num  substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];

        if(range.length > 0)
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (NSString *)formatNumber:(NSString *)mobileNumber
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

int length = (int)[mobileNumber length];
if(length > 10)
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber substringFromIndex: length-10];

}

return mobileNumber;
}

- (int)getLength:(NSString *)mobileNumber
{
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

int length = (int)[mobileNumber length];

return length;
}
```

Comment: is it applicable to all formats? I guess no. Please confirm if it is.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way, Hope this will help someone else problem also:

```
-(NSString *)getNewString:(NSString *)maskString textFieldText:(NSString *)textFieldText range:(NSRange)range newString:(NSString *)newString{

if ((range.location >= maskString.length)||((textFieldText.length-1) == range.location)) {
    return textFieldText;
}

range.length = 1;
NSMutableString *formattedStr = [textFieldText mutableCopy];
NSString *subString = [maskString substringWithRange:range];

if ([maskString characterAtIndex:range.location] != '#' )
{
    [formattedStr appendString:subString];

    if([self checkNextMaskRange:maskString WithRange:range])
        [formattedStr appendString:@" "];
}

return formattedStr;
```

}

call it like this:

```
  -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

       if (range.location == 0 && [string isEqualToString:@" "])
                    return NO;

                NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS_ONLY_NEW] invertedSet];
                NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

                NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
                 textField.text = [self getNewString:maskString textFieldText:textField.text range:range newString:string];
                return (([string isEqualToString:filtered] ) && (newLength <=maskString.length));
    }
```

Here maskString is any mask like ##-###-#### OR (###)##-##-## etc anything you can pass.